# Accessing geometry in Shape files (SHP)

Tags: import, geographics, data-format

Shape files can readily be imported and converted to a Dataset. For large shape files, this may unnecessarily consume a large amount of memory, particularly when the dataset is only used to retrieve small bits of geographical information at a time. Is there a better way of using the shape file information without importing the whole file?

I became interested in this as I was using the shape file representing the vineyards of France. Converting the large shape file to a dataset gave a MaxMemoryUsed[] = 5.5 GB. Although this dataset was perfectly usable, I decided to have a closer look at the shape file format with the goal of only importing the required geometries for a particular query. I am providing the details of this approach in my own answer to this question.

Answer (score 6):

I will use an example to demonstrate the code.  First, download the shape file "2022-05-20-delim-parcellar-aoc-shp.zip" from https://data.europa.eu/data/datasets/5aaf6b7ec751df67b0d7a87f?locale=en . Note the Open License demanding that the original producer and date be identified: **Institut national de l'origine et de la qualité (INAO), 2022-05-20**. This  will result in this directory on your system:

[image]

The **.shp** file contains the geometry of each vineyard land parcel. The **.dbf** file contains all the data, except the geometry. The **.shx** file is an index into the **.shp** file. The strategy is to import the **.dbf** file and convert it to a dataset. Queries on this dataset will return rows of interest. The row numbers (or record numbers) are then used to retrieve the indexes in the **.shx** file, which has fixed record lengths. An index is made up of the offset in the **.shp** file where the geometry information starts and the size of this geometry. We can then read the correct geometry in the **.shp** file, which has variable length records.

The **.prj** file is a text file providing geodetic information, necessary to properly interpret the coordinates. A common reference system is WGS 84, in which case the coordinates are given as latitude and longitude. However, in this case we are dealing with Lambert_93 projection. Since this post is not about geodetic, just note that a function `lambert93ToGeo[]` is used to directly convert coordinates to latitude and longitude.

Finally, a **.cpg** file is often present (not in this case) to provide the character encoding of the data (usually UTF-8 ). The presence of a **.cpg** supersedes the one-byte code provided in the **.dbf** file to indicate character encoding.

Here is a function reading a **.dbf** file and providing information about its content. Note that the function reads the character encoding byte and also check for the presence of a **.cpg** file.

```
dbfHeaderInfo[dbfPath_] :=
 
 Module[{dbfStream, fileType, year, month, day, numRecords, 
   headerSize, recordSize, skip, encodingID, fieldAssoc, fieldName, 
   fieldType, fieldLength, decimalPlaces, i, cpgFileName, cpgContent, 
   possibleEncodings},
  
  (* reading file info *)
  
  dbfStream = OpenRead[dbfPath, BinaryFormat -> True];
  fileType = BinaryRead[dbfStream, "Byte"];
  year = IntegerString@(BinaryRead[dbfStream, "Byte"] + 1900);
  month = IntegerString@(BinaryRead[dbfStream, "Byte"]);
  day = IntegerString@(BinaryRead[dbfStream, "Byte"]);
  numRecords = 
   BinaryRead[dbfStream, "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> -1];
  headerSize = 
   BinaryRead[dbfStream, "Integer16", ByteOrdering -> -1];
  recordSize = 
   BinaryRead[dbfStream, "Integer16", ByteOrdering -> -1];
  skip = BinaryRead[dbfStream, Table["Byte", 17]];
  encodingID = BinaryRead[dbfStream, "Byte"];
  skip = BinaryRead[dbfStream, Table["Byte", 2]];
  
  (* reading record fields *)
  fieldAssoc = <||>;
  i = 0;
  Do[
   i++;
   fieldName = 
    StringTrim@
     ByteArrayToString@
      ByteArray@BinaryRead[dbfStream, Table["Byte", 11]];
   fieldType = BinaryRead[dbfStream, "Character8"];
   skip = BinaryRead[dbfStream, Table["Byte", 4]];
   fieldLength = BinaryRead[dbfStream, "Byte"];
   skip = BinaryRead[dbfStream, Table["Byte", 15]];
   AppendTo[fieldAssoc, 
    i -> <|"Name" -> fieldName, "Type" -> fieldType, 
      "Size" -> fieldLength|>];
   If[BinaryRead[dbfStream, "Byte"] == 13, Break[], 
    SetStreamPosition[dbfStream, StreamPosition[dbfStream] - 1]];
   , Infinity
   ];
  
  Close[dbfStream];
  
  (* info about encodings *)
  
  possibleEncodings = <|
    0 -> "No information",
    1 -> "DOS Latin US (cp437, IBM437, CSPC8CODEPAGE437)",
    2 -> 
     "DOS Latin1 International (cp850, IBM850, CSPC850Multilingual)",
    3 -> "Windows ANSI (WindowsANSI, cp1252, Windows-1252, MS-ANSI)",
    8 -> "DOS Nordic *DanishOEM* (CP865, IBM865, CSIBM865)",
    9 -> "DOS Latin *DutchOEM* (cp437, IBM437, CSPC8CODEPAGE437)",
    10 -> 
     "DOS Latin International *DuchOEM* (cp850, IBM850, \
CSPC850Multilingual)", 
    11 -> "DOS Latin *FinnishOEM* (cp437, IBM437, CSPC8CODEPAGE437)",
    13 -> "DOS Latin *FrenchOEM* (cp437, IBM437, CSPC8CODEPAGE437)",
    14 -> 
     "DOS Latin International *FrenchOEM* (cp850, IBM850, \
CSPC850Multilingual)",
    15 -> "DOS Latin *GermanOEM* (cp437, IBM437, CSPC8CODEPAGE437)",
    16 -> 
     "DOS Latin International *GermanOEM* (cp850, IBM850, \
CSPC850Multilingual)",
    17 -> "DOS Latin *ItalianOEM* (cp437, IBM437, CSPC8CODEPAGE437)",
    18 -> 
     "DOS Latin International *ItalianOEM* (cp850, IBM850, \
CSPC850Multilingual)",
    19 -> "DOS Japanese (cp932)",
    20 -> 
     "DOS Latin International *SpanishOEM* (cp850, IBM850, \
CSPC850Multilingual)",
    21 -> "DOS Latin *SwedishOEM* (cp437, IBM437, CSPC8CODEPAGE437)",
    22 -> 
     "DOS Latin International *SwedishOEM* (cp850, IBM850, \
CSPC850Multilingual)",
    23 -> "DOS Nordic *NorwegianOEM* (CP865, IBM865, CSIBM865)",
    24 -> "DOS Latin *SpanishOEM* (cp437, IBM437, CSPC8CODEPAGE437)",
    25 -> 
     "DOS Latin *EnglishOEM Britain* (cp437, IBM437, \
CSPC8CODEPAGE437)",
    26 -> 
     "DOS Latin International *EnglishOEM Britain* (cp850, IBM850, \
CSPC850Multilingual)",
    27 -> 
     "DOS Latin *EnglishOEM US* (cp437, IBM437, CSPC8CODEPAGE437)",
    28 -> "DOS *FrenchOEM Canada* (CP863, IBM863, CSIBM863)",
    29 -> 
     "DOS Latin International *FrenchOEM* (cp850, IBM850, \
CSPC850Multilingual)",
    31 -> "DOS Latin2 *CzechOEM* (CP852, IBM852, CSPCP852)",
    34 -> "DOS Latin2 *HungarianOEM* (CP852, IBM852, CSPCP852)",
    35 -> "DOS Latin2 *PolishOEM* (CP852, IBM852, CSPCP852)",
    36 -> 
     "DOSLatin1 Multilingual *PortugueseOEM*(CP860, IBM860, CSIBM860)",
    37 -> 
     "DOS Latin International *PortugueseOEM* (cp850, IBM850, \
CSPC850Multilingual)",
    38 -> "DOS Russian(CP866, IBM866, CSIBM866)",
    55 -> 
     "DOS Latin International *EnglishOEM US* (cp850, IBM850, \
CSPC850Multilingual)",
    64 -> "DOS Latin2 *RomanianOEM* (CP852, IBM852, CSPCP852)",
    77 -> "DOS Chinese Simplified *PRC* (CP936, MS936, WINDOWS-936)",
    78 -> "DOS Korean (CP949)",
    79 -> "DOS Chinese Traditional *Taiwan* (CP950,Big5)",
    80 -> "DOS Thai (cp874, WINDOWS-874)",
    87 -> "ANSI (WindowsANSI, cp1252, Windows-1252, MS-ANSI)",
    88 -> 
     "ANSI Western Europe (WindowsANSI, cp1252, Windows-1252, \
MS-ANSI)",
    89 -> 
     "ANSI Spanish (WindowsANSI, cp1252, Windows-1252, MS-ANSI)",
    100 -> "DOS Eastern Europe (CP852, IBM852, CSPCP852)",
    101 -> "DOS Russian (CP866, IBM866, CSIBM866)",
    102 -> "DOS Nordic (CP865, IBM865, CSIBM865)",
    103 -> "DOS Icelandic (CP861, IBM861, CSIBM861)",
    106 -> "DOS Greek (CP737)",
    107 -> "DOS Turkish (CP857, IBM857, CSIBM857)",
    108 -> "DOS French-Canadian (CP863, IBM863, CSIBM863)",
    120 -> "Big 5 Taiwan (CP950,Big5)" ,
    121 -> "Hangul (CP949)",
    122 -> "PRC GBK (CP936, MS936, WINDOWS-936)",
    123 -> "Japanese Shift-JIS (CP932)",
    124 -> "Windows Thai (WindowsThai,CP874)",
    134 -> "DOS *GreekOEM* (CP737)",
    135 -> "DOS Latin2 *SlovenianOEM* (CP852, IBM852, CSPCP852)",
    136 -> "DOS *TurkishOEM* (CP857, IBM857, CSIBM857)",
    200 -> 
     "Windows Eastern Europe (WindowsEastEurope, CP1250, MS-EE, \
WINDOWS-1250)",
    201 -> 
     "Windows Cyrillic (WindowsCyrillic, CP1251, MS-CYRL, \
WINDOWS-1251)",
    202 -> 
     "Windows Latin5 Turkish (WindowsTurkish, CP1254, MS-TURK, \
WINDOWS-1254)" ,
    203 -> 
     "Windows Greek (WindowsGreek, CP1253, MS-GREEK, WINDOWS-1253)",
    204 -> 
     "Windows BalticRim (WindowsBaltic, CP1257, WINBALTRIM, \
WINDOWS-1257)"
    |>;
  
  (* check if there is a .cpg file *)
  
  cpgFileName = StringJoin[{StringDrop[dbfPath, -3], "cpg"}];
  cpgContent = "File not found";
  If[FileExistsQ[cpgFileName], cpgContent = ReadString[cpgFileName]];
  
  (* build data set*)
  Dataset@<|
    "File" -> FileNameTake[dbfPath],
    "Last update" -> year <> "-" <> month <> "-" <> day,
    "Number of records" -> numRecords,
    "Size of header" -> headerSize,
    "Size of record" -> recordSize,
    "Encoding info (.dbf)" -> Key[encodingID][possibleEncodings],
    "Encoding info (.cpg)" -> cpgContent,
    "Fields" -> Dataset@fieldAssoc
    |>
  ]
```

This is the result of calling this function with our **.dbf** file:

[image]

The function `dbfData[]` reads the **.dbf** file and constructs associations:

```
Options[dbfData] = {"CharEncoding" -> "UTF-8", "DBFields" -> All, 
   "IgnoreRecordsMarkedForDeletion" -> True};
dbfData[dbfPath_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 
 Module[{skip, numRecords, headerSize, recordSize, fieldAssoc, i, 
   fieldName, fieldType, fieldLength, recAssoc, requiredFields, 
   record, delMark, fieldRanges, str, dbfStream, offset, fieldData, 
   val, rf},
  
  (* reading file info *)
  
  dbfStream = OpenRead[dbfPath, BinaryFormat -> True];
  skip = BinaryRead[dbfStream, Table["Byte", 4]];
  numRecords = 
   BinaryRead[dbfStream, "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> -1];
  headerSize = 
   BinaryRead[dbfStream, "Integer16", ByteOrdering -> -1];
  recordSize = 
   BinaryRead[dbfStream, "Integer16", ByteOrdering -> -1];
  skip = BinaryRead[dbfStream, Table["Byte", 20]];
  
  (* reading record fields info *)
  fieldAssoc = <||>;
  i = 0;
  Do[
   i++;
   fieldName = 
    StringTrim@
     ByteArrayToString@
      ByteArray@
       DeleteCases[BinaryRead[dbfStream, Table["Byte", 11]], 0];
   fieldType = BinaryRead[dbfStream, "Character8"];
   skip = BinaryRead[dbfStream, Table["Byte", 4]];
   fieldLength = BinaryRead[dbfStream, "Byte"];
   skip = BinaryRead[dbfStream, Table["Byte", 15]];
   AppendTo[fieldAssoc, 
    i -> <|"Name" -> fieldName, "Type" -> fieldType, 
      "Size" -> fieldLength|>];
   If[BinaryRead[dbfStream, "Byte"] == 13, Break[], 
    SetStreamPosition[dbfStream, StreamPosition[dbfStream] - 1]];
   , Infinity
   ];
  
  (* process records *)
  recAssoc = <||>;
  If[OptionValue["DBFields"] === All, 
   requiredFields = Range[Length[fieldAssoc]], 
   requiredFields = OptionValue["DBFields"]];
  offset = 1;
  fieldRanges = {#["Name"], #["Type"], #["Size"], 
      offset, (offset = #["Size"] + offset; Nothing)} & /@ 
    fieldAssoc;
  fieldData = {};
  
  Monitor[
   i = 1;
   While[i <= numRecords,
    record = 
     ByteArray@BinaryRead[dbfStream, Table["Byte", recordSize]];
    If[OptionValue["IgnoreRecordsMarkedForDeletion"] && 
      record[[1]] == 42, i++; Continue[]];
    
    j = 1;
    While[j <= Length[requiredFields],
     rf = requiredFields[[j]];
     val = 
      record[[
       fieldRanges[[rf]][[4]] + 1 ;; 
        fieldRanges[[rf]][[4]] + fieldRanges[[rf]][[3]]]];
     
     Which[
      fieldRanges[[rf]][[2]] == "C",
      str = 
       StringTrim@
        ByteArrayToString[val, OptionValue["CharEncoding"]];
      AppendTo[fieldData, fieldRanges[[rf]][[1]] -> str],
      
      fieldRanges[[rf]][[2]] == "N" || 
       fieldRanges[[rf]][[2]] == "F",  (* 
      Numeric or Float field converted to a number *)
      
      str = 
       StringTrim@
        ByteArrayToString[val, OptionValue["CharEncoding"]];
      AppendTo[fieldData, fieldRanges[[rf]][[1]] -> ToExpression[str]],
      
      fieldRanges[[rf]][[2]] == "L",  (* 
      Logical field converted to True or False *)
      
      str = 
       StringTrim@
        ByteArrayToString[val, OptionValue["CharEncoding"]];
      Which[
       ToUpperCase[str] == "T" || ToUpperCase[str] == "Y",
       AppendTo[fieldData, fieldRanges[[rf]][[1]] -> True],
       
       ToUpperCase[str] == "F" || ToUpperCase[str] == "N",
       AppendTo[fieldData, fieldRanges[[rf]][[1]] -> False],
       
       True, (* anything other then T,t,F,f,N,n,Y,
       y is kept as String - Note: uninitialized field is a "?" *)
   
           
       str = 
        StringTrim@ByteArrayToString[val, OptionValue["CharEncoding"]];
       AppendTo[fieldData, fieldRanges[[rf]][[1]] -> str]
       ],
      
      True, (* Date and Memo fields are kept as Strings *)
      
      str = 
       StringTrim@
        ByteArrayToString[val, OptionValue["CharEncoding"]];
      AppendTo[fieldData, fieldRanges[[rf]][[1]] -> str]
      ];
     j++;
     ];
    AppendTo[recAssoc, i -> <|fieldData|>];
    i++;
    ], ProgressIndicator[i, {1, numRecords}]];
  
  Close[dbfStream];
  
  recAssoc
  ]
```

We will now create our main dataset used for our queries. Only 5 of the 17 fields were selected: the wine appellation (app), the denomination (denom), the commune id code (insee), the commune name (nomcom), and the large wine region (grp_name2).

```
vineyardDataset = 
 Dataset@
  dbfData[
   "<<YOUR PATH>> /2022-05-20-delim-parcellaire-aoc-shp/2022-05-20_delim_\
parcellaire_aoc_shp.dbf", "DBFields" -> {7, 9, 10, 11, 17}, 
   "CharEncoding" -> "WindowsANSI"]
```

[image]

The first column shows sequential row numbers. These will be used to compute the location of the indexes in the **.shx** file. Suppose we want to know about the geometry of land parcels (vineyards) allowed to produce grapes for wine with denomination "Aloxe-Corton" :

```
aloxeCorton = 
 vineyardDataset[
  Select[#denom == "Aloxe-Corton" &], <|"Commune code" -> "insee", 
   "Commune" -> "nomcom", "Wine region" -> "grp_name2"|>]
```

[image]

We can now extract the list of keys:

```
keyList = Normal@Keys@aloxeCorton
(* {4622,4623,4624} *)
```

The function `shapePointers[]` will retrieve the indexes from the **.shx** file. Calling the function gives a list of associations. Only the right side of each association is required. It represents the offset and size of the geometry data in the **.shp** file:

```
shapePointers[shxPath_, keyList_] :=
 Module[{shxStream, assocList},
  shxStream = OpenRead[shxPath, BinaryFormat -> True];
  assocList = {};
  AppendTo[assocList,
     SetStreamPosition[shxStream, 100 + 8 (# - 1)];
     # -> {BinaryRead[shxStream, "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> 1]*2, 
       BinaryRead[shxStream, "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> 1]*2}
     ] & /@ keyList;
  Close[shxStream];
  assocList
  ]

shapeList = 
 shapePointers[
  "<<YOUR PATH>> /2022-05-20-delim-parcellaire-aoc-shp/2022-05-20_delim_\
parcellaire_aoc_shp.shx", keyList]

(* {4622 -> {200501536, 46740}, 4623 -> {200548284, 4364}, 
 4624 -> {200552656, 6924}} *)
```

Here are the function `lambert93ToGeo[]` to convert the coordinates and the final function `readPolygonShape[]`, which retrieves the geometries, convert the coordinates and provide data ready for GeoGraphics.

```
lambert93ToGeo[X_, Y_] := (Module[{lat, lon, R, prelon, isoLat, k0},
    With[
    {
     (* Lambert-93 projection constants *)
     n = 0.7256077650, (* 
     n *)
     cm = 11754255.426,(* C *)
     xs = 700000.000, (* 
     Subscript[X, S] *)
     ys = 12655612.050, (* Subscript[Y, S] *)

          cml = 3.0 * Pi/180, (* 
     central meridian longitude (3 degrees) in radian *)
     
     (* Reference ellipsoid constant GRS80 *)
     
     ec = 0.08181919112  (* eccentricity *)
     },
    
    R = Sqrt[(X - xs)^2 + (Y - ys)^2];
    prelon = ArcTan[(X - xs)/(ys - Y)];
    lon = cml + (prelon/n);
    isoLat = -Log[R/cm]/n; (* isometric latitude *)
    
    k0 = 2 ArcTan[E^isoLat] - Pi/2;
    
    (* latitude requires successive iterations to increase accuracy - 
    here iterated 3 times *) 
    lat = 
     Nest[ 
      2 ArcTan[(((1 + ec Sin[#])/(1 - ec Sin[#]))^(ec/2) E^isoLat)] - 
        Pi/2 &, k0, 3];
    
    (180/Pi {lat, lon})
    ]]
  )

Options[readPolygonShape] = {"ConvertFromLambert93" -> False};
readPolygonShape[shpPath_, shapePointer_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 
 Module[{shpStream, readRecordNumber, readContentLength, skip, 
   numRings, numPoints, indices, pointsList, dif, poly},
  
  shpStream = OpenRead[shpPath, BinaryFormat -> True];
  SetStreamPosition[shpStream, Values[shapePointer][[1]]];
  
  (* verifiy record number and length match the shx file *)
  
  readRecordNumber = 
   BinaryRead[shpStream, "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> 1];
  readContentLength = 
   BinaryRead[shpStream, "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> 1]*2;
  If[readRecordNumber != Keys[shapePointer] || 
    readContentLength != Values[shapePointer][[2]], 
   Echo["Mismatch detected"]];
  
  (* verify that we have a Polygon type. If not, Return *)
  
  If[BinaryRead[shpStream, "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> -1] != 5, 
   Return["Not a Polygon shape"]];
  
  (* skip the bounding box *)
  
  skip = BinaryRead[shpStream, Table["Byte", 32]];
  
  (* get the number of rings *)
  
  numRings = BinaryRead[shpStream, "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> -1];
  
  (* get the number of points *)
  
  numPoints = BinaryRead[shpStream, "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> -1];
  
  (* get indices of starting point of each ring *)
  
  indices = 
   BinaryRead[shpStream, Table["Integer32", numRings], 
    ByteOrdering -> -1];
  
  (* read points *)
  AppendTo[indices, numPoints];
  dif = Differences[indices];
  pointsList = 
   Partition[BinaryRead[shpStream, Table["Real64", 2 #]], 2] & /@ 
    dif;
  Close[shpStream];
  
  If[OptionValue["ConvertFromLambert93"], 
   pointsList = 
    pointsList /. {x_Real, y_Real} -> lambert93ToGeo[x, y]];
  poly = FilledCurve@Line[pointsList];
  poly = poly /. {_Integer, _Integer} -> Nothing;
  poly = poly /. a : {{_Real, _Real} ..} -> GeoPosition[a];
  pointsList = FilledCurve@Line@GeoPosition@pointsList;
  pointsList
  ]
```

And finally calling the function and drawing the map.

```
cp = readPolygonShape[
     "<<YOUR PATH>>/2022-05-20-delim-parcellaire-aoc-shp/2022-05-20_delim_\
parcellaire_aoc_shp.shp", #, "ConvertFromLambert93" -> True] & /@ 
   shapeList;
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], FaceForm[Red], cp}, 
 GeoBackground -> "VectorClassic", 
 GeoRangePadding -> Quantity[1, "km"]]
```

[image]

Note that the above assumes that we are dealing with Polygon shape files. The following function called with the **.shp** file returns the type of shape file.

```
shapeType[shpPath_] :=
 Module[{type, shpStream, typeByte},
  type = <|
    0 -> "Null Shape",
    1 -> "Point",
    3 -> "Polyline",
    5 -> "Polygon",
    8 -> "MultiPoint",
    11 -> "PointZ",
    13 -> "PolylineZ",
    15 -> "PolygonZ",
    18 -> "MultipointZ",
    21 -> "PointM",
    23 -> "PolyLineM",
    25 -> "PolygonM",
    28 -> "MultiPointM",
    31 -> "MultiPatch"
    |>;
  shpStream = OpenRead[shpPath, BinaryFormat -> True];
  SetStreamPosition[shpStream, 32];
  typeByte = BinaryRead[shpStream, "Byte"];
  Close[shpStream];
  Key[typeByte][type]
  ]
```

Comment: This is very nice! Thank you for contributing it!